# how to expand horizantal recyclerview into vertical

Tags: android

I using normal `recyclerview`  and set to `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL`, now when I click on button `recyclerview` should expand to vertical and If I click on the button again it should set back to horizontal `recylerview` again.

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topCategoryTxt" />
```

onButtonClick

```
if (LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL == 0) {
                    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(HomeScreen.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    recyclerview.setAdapter(popularItemsAdapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else{
          layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(HomeScreen.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    recyclerview.setAdapter(popularItemsAdapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Condition is always being 0
how to change it dynamically
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean orientaion = false

if (!orientaion) {
                layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(HomeScreen.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                recyclerview.setAdapter(popularItemsAdapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                orientaion=true;
            }else{
      layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(HomeScreen.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                recyclerview.setAdapter(popularItemsAdapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                orientaion=false;
}
```